# how can add special symbols in button content using xaml in windows 8 metro application?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to set the content of a button to a special character used by XAML `(`,`}`,`<`, `{`, and `)`. However, when I put that in the `Content=""` tag, the program does not compile and I'm told that my XAML is invalid.

How can I use these characters for a button's text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for all special characters in the XAML file.

```
Button Content="{Binding Source= \{}"
```

I used the `\` escape character before the `{`.

Comment: What if i need to add / character itself ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the character code.  Run charmap and select the font you're using and look at the character code of the character you want.  Then use the format from below to set the Content.

```
<Button Content="&#x0028;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

( = 0028

} = 007D

< = 003C

{ = 007B

) = 0029